# Formula Field Changing the Date to Today

Tags: formula-field, salesforce-id

I have made a formula field to populate the date to today when a checked box is true and get locked its changing everytime its edited and saved.

Like if the checkbox was true on 8/7/2015
It changes the date to 9/7/2015 when a lead is saved again

```
IF((Do_Not_Contact__c = True ),Today(), Null)
```

Answer (score 8):

Your formula evaluates every time you retrieve it's value. So at any point in time your formula will evaluate `today()` which will be the actual date/time.

The solution would be to create a workflow that updates a new date field with the same formula, that way you time stamp it, then make the new date field `read only` on the page layout.